Clarification about continuity of cost function
I've come across the statement that the following function, referred to as Coulomb cost in optimal transport, is lower semicontinuous: $c : \mathbb{R}^{Nd} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, c(x_1,.., x_N) = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq N}\frac{1}{|x_i - x_j|}$ (for example, this paper: https://flore.unifi.it/bitstream/2158/1070973/1/m2an150051.pdf, Remark 3.14).
It is assumed to be $\infty$ when $x_j = x_j$ for two indices $i \neq j.$ The function is continuous when $x_i \neq x_j, \forall 1 \leq i < j \leq N,$ so I'm wondering about the pathological case where it is $\infty$. If we take $N=2$ for simplicity, for every sequence $(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow (x,x), \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} c(x_n, y_n) = \infty = c(x,x),$ because $c(x_n, y_n)$ diverges. My confusion: Why is this specifically stated as lower semicontinuous and not simply continuous? We would also get $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} c(x_n,y_n) \leq \infty = c(x,x),$ (actually "$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} c(x_n,y_n) = \infty = c(x,x)$"), so why not simply continuous?

The Remark is not saying that it is not continuous. The remark is about general cost functions and it refers to the Coulomb cost as one of such potentials. That said, it is not clear from the remark if the authors consider an unbounded function as continuous. Usually, when talking about continuous functions, one assumes that the codomain is $\mathbb R$, unless explicitly stated. I would find it strange if the authors said that the Coulomb cost is continuous without soecifying the domain. For l.s.c. functions, often one assumes that the codomain of the function is $[-\infty,\infty]$ instead.

Thank you! What's the reason for the different assumption regaring the codomain? Why does one usually assume the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ for continuous functions?

You can imagine that continuous functions are everywhere in analysis, so there are some general common practices that are well established. My impression is that if you say “$1/|x|$ is a continuous function” without further context, people would say “Uhm… what do you mean…?”. But l.s.c. functions are often defined on the extended reals to my very limited experience, and regardless, the definition makes sense even if the codomain is $\mathbb R$ even for unbounded functions, so a sentence like “$1/|x|$ is a l.s.c. function” might need less context, depending on the authors and research field.
